# CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX in catkin_make vs catkin tools

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to make our build compatible with catkin_make and catkin tools, but how CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX is handled in the two tools is causing me some trouble.

We have some (non-ROS) tools that generate headers that need to be included by the current package being built, and by downstream packages. Our pure-cmake build system would create these headers in the out-of-source build directory and install them into the install directory. Downstream packages would include the $INSTALL/include directory and all would be well. We adapted our build to be catkin_make compatible by copying the files into ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/include at configure time, and downstream packages could find them by adding ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/include to their include path.

This doesn't work with catkin tools, because CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX points to a devel/.private directory and then symlinks content into devel space. Is there a variable available at configure time in CMake that points to workspace/devel that is available in both catkin_make and catkin tools?

I know this problem can be solved by making foo-extras.cmake.develspace.in and foo-extras.cmake.installspace.in for each project, but that'll be a huge pain. A variable that is consistent between the two tools that points to the workspace/devel directory would be a lot more straightforward.

Thanks,
-Mark

---

Edit: Creating a minimal example would take a fair amount of work, I'll point to some of the relevant files and hopefully that will be sufficient.

Here's our cmake macro for generating source from RTI DDS IDL:
https://github.com/mallanmba/irg_cmake/blob/catkin_build/Modules/GenerateRtiDdsIdl.cmake

Here's a CMakeLists.txt that uses the macro:
https://github.com/mallanmba/soraCore/blob/master/knRapid/src/rapidDds/CMakeLists.txt

There's a block at the end that checks for `catkin_FOUND` and copies the generated headers into devel space. If that block is not there, none of the headers show up in devel space. I've never observed catkin_make or catkin_tools putting headers into devel space unless I explicitly copy them there. How is the "automatic" placement of includes in devel supposed to work?

The issue that I'm having with `CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX` between catkin_make and catkin tools is that catkin_make sets that variable to `foo_ws/devel` and catkin tools sets it to `foo_ws/devel/.private/bar_project` and then symlinks into `foo_ws/devel`. If I have project_B that depends on generated headers from project_A, and I add `${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_GLOBAL_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}` to the include path of a project_B, it works fine for catkin_make. But it fails for catkin tools because `${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}` is pointing to foo_ws/devel/.private/project_B, and project_B can't see project_A's generated headers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248718/catkin_devel_prefix-in-catkin_make-vs-catkin-tools/) by [mallanmba](https://answers.ros.org/users/6388/mallanmba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-12-07**:
In response to the "automatic" placement of headers into the devel space, if the package is a cmake package, then the catkin tools will `make install` with the install prefix set to the devel space. If it is a catkin package then it does need to be copied.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-12-07**:
I think the issue is that you assume that two different packages will share the same devel space. I think your packages would also fail to work if you split them between two catkin workspaces (even if you build them both with `catkin_make`).

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-12-07**:
Instead you should `find_package` project_A from project_B and add the include directories exported by project_A in the `CMakeLists.txt` for project_B.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-12-07**:
Put another way, Project A generates files and puts them in a folder, then exports that folder in the `project_A_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable and then project B does `find_package(... project_A)` and adds the folder it exported as an include directory with the CMake macro `include_directories(...)`.

**Comment by [mallanmba](https://answers.ros.org/users/6388/mallanmba/) on 2016-12-07**:
Is there an easier way to export `foo_INCLUDE_DIRS` than having to create `foo-extras.cmake.installspace.in` and `foo-extras.cmake.develspace.in` for each project? The `catkin_package()` INCLUDE_DIRS is relative to `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` which doesn't help

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-12-07**:
This line from `gencpp` (which also generates header files like this and makes them available in the devel space), adds the include directory to be exported automatically by the `catkin_package` call: https://github.com/ros/gencpp/blob/indigo-devel/cmake/gencpp-extras.cmake.em#L54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your packages are plain cmake, then catkin tools will "install" all the files to the devel space, so you need not copy the files. If you packages are catkin packages, then the `CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX` cmake variable should be set. I don't see any reason this shouldn't work in catkin tools as it does in `catkin_make`. Please provide a minimal example of the problem or instructions on how to reproduce the issue with your packages if you want someone to look into it in more detail.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1